# Could not autowire field in spring using spring-boot

Tags: spring, hibernate

I've been trying to get my head around `spring & hibernate` in the past 4-5 days and I feel like I'm nearly their...I'm really confused to why I'm getting these `auto-wire` errors.

I'm trying to create a `rest api` so I've gone with the *mvc* pattern.

Does anyone have any idea why I'm getting these errors? I've provided my setup and stack trace below.

#### Controller package: **spring.controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
@Component
public class userController {
    @Autowired
    userService userService;


    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/list" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listUsers(ModelMap model) {
        List<user> users = userService.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("users", users);
        return "userslist";
    }

}
```

#### UserServiceImpl package: spring.service

```
import hibernate.dao.userDAO;


@Service("userService")
@Transactional
public class userServiceImpl implements userService {
    @Autowired
    userDAO dao;

    public List<user> findAll() {
        return dao.list();
    }
    public user findById() {
        return null;
    }
    public void saveuser(user p) { }
    public void updateuser(user p) {}
}
```

#### UserService

```
public interface userService {
    List<user> findAll();
    user findById();
    void saveuser(user p);
    void updateuser(user p);

}
```

#### userDAOImpl package: hibernate.dao

```
@Repository("userDAO")
public class userDAOImpl extends AbstractDao<Integer, user> implements userDAO {

    public List<user> list() {
        Criteria criteria = createEntityCriteria().addOrder(Order.asc("firstName"));
        criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);//To avoid duplicates.
        List<user> users = (List<user>) criteria.list();

        return users;
    }

    public void save(user ps) {
        persist(ps);
    }

}
```

#### AbstractDao package: hibernate.dao

```
public abstract class AbstractDao<PK extends Serializable, T> {

    private final Class<T> persistentClass;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public AbstractDao(){
        this.persistentClass =(Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass
                ()).getActualTypeArguments()[1];
    }

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected Session getSession(){
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T getByKey(PK key) {
        return (T) getSession().get(persistentClass, key);
    }

    public void persist(T entity) {
        getSession().persist(entity);
    }

    public void delete(T entity) {
        getSession().delete(entity);
    }

    protected Criteria createEntityCriteria(){
        return getSession().createCriteria(persistentClass);
    }

}
```

#### applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="spring.controller" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="hibernate.dao" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="hibernate.model" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="spring.service" />
</beans>
```

#### Stack trace

```
[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:478)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: spring.service.userService spring.controller.userController.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: hibernate.dao.userDAO spring.service.userServiceImpl.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [hibernate.dao.userDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
        at spring.Main.main(Main.java:58)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: spring.service.userService spring.controller.userController.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: hibernate.dao.userDAO spring.service.userServiceImpl.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [hibernate.dao.userDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: hibernate.dao.userDAO spring.service.userServiceImpl.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [hibernate.dao.userDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: hibernate.dao.userDAO spring.service.userServiceImpl.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [hibernate.dao.userDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
        ... 36 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [hibernate.dao.userDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
        ... 38 more
```

#### Edit 1

I tried removing the label inside `@Repository("userDAO")` and make it `@Repository`. As suggested in one of the answers.

This didn't change anything.

#### Edit 2

Here is my main class:

```
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {
    private static final SessionFactory ourSessionFactory;
    private static final ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    static {
        try {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure();

            serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();
            ourSessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static Session getSession() throws HibernateException {
        return ourSessionFactory.openSession();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

#### Edit 3:

After trying m.deinum's solution, I got the following stack trace...Removing the daoImpl and abstractImpl was a good idea. But I still keep getting these Error creating bean with name **X**: Injection of autowired dependices failed exceptions...

Stack trace after adapting my code to suit the below answer:

```
[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:478)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: spring.service.userService spring.controller.userController.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: hibernate.dao.userDAO spring.service.userServiceImpl.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [hibernate.dao.userDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180)
        at spring.Main.main(Main.java:44)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: spring.service.userService spring.controller.userController.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: hibernate.dao.userDAO spring.service.userServiceImpl.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [hibernate.dao.userDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: hibernate.dao.userDAO spring.service.userServiceImpl.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [hibernate.dao.userDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: hibernate.dao.userDAO spring.service.userServiceImpl.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [hibernate.dao.userDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
        ... 36 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [hibernate.dao.userDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1373)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1119)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
        ... 38 more
```

Comment: Show your `Main` class.

Comment: I added the main class @M.Deinum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters currently your `applicationContext.xml` is pretty much useless. If you would remove it, restart and you would still get the same exception. This is due to how Spring Boot (by default) works.

Your `Main` class is defined in the `spring` package. Spring Boot automatically scans this packages and all of its sub packages. However your dao etc. is in `hibernate` not covered by the Spring Boot component scanning.

Either add `@ImportResource("location-of-your/applicationContext.xml")` or simply add `@ComponentScan({"spring","hibernate"})` to your main class, or move your DAO's to a sub package of `spring`.

Your code is also flawed, you are using Spring then use Spring, don't configure hibernate yourself. Use a `LocalSessionFactoryBean` for this and let Spring handle all that for you.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {   

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
     return new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    }
}
```

However instead of using plain Hibernate and rolling yet another abstract dao, I suggest you remove all that. Use JPA together with Spring Data JPA, saves you a lot of code. (Remove user `userDaoImpl` and `AbstractDao` and all the interfaces that come with it).

Your `userDao` would look like.

```
public interface userDao extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {}
```

(Yes that is it nothing more nothing less and yes no implementation).

You can then also remove the `sessionFactory` method from your `Main` class. Your `userService` would need to change, to use a `findAll` instead of `list`.

```
@Service("userService")
@Transactional
public class userServiceImpl implements userService {
    @Autowired
    userDAO dao;

    public List<user> findAll() {
        return dao.findAll();
    }
    ...
}
```

The general advice is use the framework (and first read some documentation) instead of trying old ways with new frameworks.

**Pro Tip:** Use a accepted naming convention `userServiceImpl` etc. isn't really custom in Java land, start with an uppercase letter `UserServiceImpl`.

Comment: I tried this, removing the userDaoImpl was a great idea, I still seem to be having trouble with the auto-wiring stuff!

Comment: Because those things are in a different packages, see the first part of the answer.

Comment: I moved my main class to the `src/main/java/` root, I also added `@ComponentScan({"spring","hibernate"})` to the top of `public class Main {`, that should've fixed it right? I also tried moving the `dao+model` packages inside the `spring` package

Comment: Please don't add your main class to the root package, that is a very bad idea it will scan ALL packages now. Also you did add `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` to your list of dependencies?

Comment: `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` is in my list. OKay, I've moved it the main method to a sub-package.

Comment: I strongly suggest adding all classes in sub packages of your main `spring` package. The fact that your dao isn't found is because by default spring boot adds the root to all package scans. However as it is in `hibernate` you also have to add `@EnableJpaRepositories("hibernate.dao")` to your root class. If you put everything in the same package structure that isn't needed and Sprig Boot will auto configure all of that.

Comment: After many more hours of playing around, I can confirm that this helped me a lot! Except the fact that using `LocalSessionFactoryBean` in the main class was crashing my application, so I added my `hibernate.cfg.xml`, and it came back to life!

Comment: Don't add `hibernate.cfg.xml` you are using JPA now, create a `persistence.xml` or add the required properties to the `application.properties`. `see http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-configure-jpa-properties

Comment: Ah right. So I'm assuming I won't be able to use hql or any of hibernates features?!

Comment: Why wouldn't that be possible... What specific hibernate features do you need that aren't supported by JPA?

Comment: I'm using intelliJ, it seems to require a config file to map everything together (auto completions and etc..)

Comment: Auto completions on what? Sorry I still don't see why you would need what you request.

Comment: For instance when using the INTELLIJ IDE, it relies on the xml config files to run the application, and do autocompletes on the hibernate querys (hsql)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove name from

```
@Repository("userDAO")
public class userDAOImpl extends AbstractDao<Integer, user> implements userDAO {
```

make it

```
@Repository
public class userDAOImpl extends AbstractDao<Integer, user> implements userDAO {
```

Comment: In which package do you have `userDAOImpl` class?

Comment: `hibernate.dao` - I added the package locations above ^^

Answer (score 0):

It could be caused by you defined multiple `<component-scan>`. The latest one's `<context:component-scan base-package="spring.service" />` is taking effect. From the exception, Spring was instantiating service beans indeed.

Just use

```
<context:component-scan base-package="spring.controller, hibernate.dao, hibernate.model,spring.service" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't fix it.

Comment: Print something in AbstractDao's constructor, if nothing is shown, then the DAO is not being instantiating.

Comment: Nothing is being printed...Although I'm not sure why the daos aren't being instantiated.

Comment: Not sure, you could be missing @ImportResource("classpath:applicationContext.xml") on your Main  application class?  Is your Service class in same package as the Main?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the @Qualifier annotation in the below locations:

```
public class userController {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userService")
    userService userService;
```

and

```
@Service("userService")
@Transactional
public class userServiceImpl implements userService {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDAO")
    userDAO dao;
```

and check.

Comment: did that fix the issue?